# 22.04 upgrade "Could not download the upgrades" ... Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::22 443]

Tags: software-installation, 22.04

thank you for your time.

I can't upgrade my updated 20.04.5 to 22.04 due to this issue.

[image]

This abort the installation.

Update. This bug is on Lauchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1990798

We are thinking it comes from ESM

Thank you in advance for your feedback.

José. France
See this [thread in French here](https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=2075230).

---

Is Ubuntu Advantage and ESM the same thing?

See what I have already done for ua:

```
jrd_10@my-pc:~$ sudo ua detach
This machine is not attached to an Ubuntu Pro subscription.
See https://ubuntu.com/pro
jrd_10@my-pc:~$
```

Thank you in advance for your feedback.

Comment: Did you enable ESM on your environment?  If you didn't, then it shouldn't even be testing the ESM repositories.  If you did, then that's part of your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I don't think I have done that but my Ubuntu has been installed by Dell (I have Dell G3 15).

This bug has been noted here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1990798

Comment: Ubuntu Advantage is rebranded Ubuntu Pro, and yes Ubuntu Pro provides ESM access but only if you attach it to a plan (even if it's a free personal).  I think your system got set up incorrectly by Dell and they 'enabled' ESM and then installed things.  We can sort of fix this, go to https://ubuntu.com/pro and sign up with your own personal email, get your personal 5 machines subscription (FREE), run through the `sudo ua attach` process, then try your updates again.

Comment: ALSO, don't add follow up information or questions as answers, this is a Q/A site not a discussion forum system.

Comment: Hi @ThomasWard, I am not sure to have understood your comment :).

Comment: Thank you for your comment on Ubuntu Pro @ThomasWard. 
Ok I will try this :).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140212/discussion-between-jrd10-and-thomas-ward).

Comment: Hi @ThomasWard. Thank you. It works :) I am on 22.04 upgrade OK :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I ran into this same problem. For some reason, apparently, some repos from https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu were configured as package sources on my machine, at least that was the case when I tried the upgrade to 22.04. I did never knowingly or willingly activate anything ESM – I‌ didn't even know about this before this issue.

The sources list had these files:

```
$ ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
[...]
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  37 Dez 30 14:23 ubuntu-esm-apps.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 303 Dez 30 14:17 ubuntu-esm-apps.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  37 Dez 30 14:23 ubuntu-esm-apps.list.save
[...]
```

... with content like:

```
deb https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu focal-apps-security main
# deb-src https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu focal-apps-security main

deb https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu focal-apps-updates main
# deb-src https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu focal-apps-updates main
```

My solution was to remove those package sources and their files and then re-intend the upgrade. Worked for me.